# How to create a pgp key with php?

Tags: php, cryptography, pear, pgp

I want to create the pgp key with php.

I'm using the Crypt_GPG library to do this. I have no problem coding and decoding with an external key.
If I want to produce a key here, he gives me the fingerprint.

https://github.com/pear/Crypt_GPG/blob/master/tests/KeyGeneratorTest.php

```php
$generator = new \Crypt_GPG_KeyGenerator(array('binary'  => '/usr/bin/gpg2', 'homedir' => 'pgphome/', 'debug' => false));
$key = $generator->setExpirationDate(2000000000)->generateKey(
    new Crypt_GPG_UserId(
        'Test Keypair <generate-test@example.com>'
    )
);
```

I hope to have private and public keys instead of fingerprints. Like this;

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
Version: BCPG C# v1.6.1.0

lQOsBFzmomwBCACKQjZRXY2TSIEUr+S5V3jK6hA+U/7W2y7X9KJojcNSQY9rDh7E
7OtNQaXEpYeJAd4b9S1ZPMAZJ+wVFl0apOGzcjRT1a/s0GrIyq+SeI32CcHXA8Kh
......
Lji4mK7gT8LbOdeZehPgIp1LH3s9cG/tpyNUzHBZwgTtS6bEvgFSMxBVKRHWJH0k
Yfmc85ah7fZZkmbek9x5W5KKhzPgujCrZT/d0xiBIRp7cr8DAcJ2
=ehq/
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
```

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: BCPG C# v1.6.1.0

mQENBFzmomwBCACKQjZRXY2TSIEUr+S5V3jK6hA+U/7W2y7X9KJojcNSQY9rDh7E
7OtNQaXEpYeJAd4b9S1ZPMAZJ+wVFl0apOGzcjRT1a/s0GrIyq+SeI32CcHXA8Kh
.....
vy44uJiu4E/C2znXmXoT4CKdSx97PXBv7acjVMxwWcIE7UumxL4BUjMQVSkR1iR9
JGH5nPOWoe32WZJm3pPceVuSiocz4Lowq2U/3dMYgSEae3K/AwHCdg==
=jEjZ
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Comment: The fingerprints are over the keys, so the keys are generated and stored *somewhere* in a key ring. If you're unsure of where they are stored then give explicit locations.

Comment: Hi; @MaartenBodewes How can I do that.

Comment: Yeah, I can get why you get confused over that. Generally programmers try and look it up [in the API documentation](https://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_GPG/docs/latest/Crypt_GPG/Crypt_GPG_KeyGenerator.html#method__construct). This is a textual description on what a function does, which hopefully is correct to the point to being usable.